# $SO(n)$ algebra relations in the vector rep

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

The $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ algebra has some relations between generators always indicated as
$$\left[T_{ij}, T_{kl}\right] = \delta_{ik}T_{jl} - \delta_{jk}T_{li} - \delta_{jl} T_{ik}  + \delta_{il}T_{jk}$$

now I would like to know how to indicate this in a vector rep, i.e. by objects intrinsically with one index. In particular, I am asking the explicit form of the structure constants
$$\left[T_a, T_b\right] = F_{ab}^{\phantom{ab}c}T_c\, .$$

Comment: I think its more common and natural to keep the basis elements indexed by the i,j.

Comment: thanks, that's why I asked :)